# How do I repair a damaged sailing boat?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Is it possible to repair a damaged sailing boat?
If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. Boats are not repairable. If it is broken, leave it behind and look for a new one. There are a lot of them all over the map. Usually, you don't have to walk longer than 10 minutes to find one.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to repair a damaged or even broken boat.

[Steamcommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/app/292030/discussions/0/613958868376028377/)